# Need Bath sink Oval overflow trim ring -Large Oval

Tags: bathtub, sink, trim, cover

I have a 1960's American Standard vintage bath wall shelf sink that I'm refurbishing.   My Oval overflow hole is rusted chipped and poor condition and I want to add a trim ring to help hide the rust / porcelain chip out.   I CAN find an oval trim ring online - but they are all too small.   My hole measures 2 7/16" wide by 1/2" high.  (Items I've found are not wide enough).
Suggestions ??    Source for trim ring of larger size?    Other comments ??

Otherwise the sink looks good - but the overflow hole looks like crap.     Thanks All !!

Comment: This boils down to a "shopping" question which is explicitly off-topic. That said, you may have to expand your search beyond the plumbing section - you basically need _something_ that will fit the hole & look decent, it doesn't have to have been designed for a sink. You may need to 3D print something, or make it (or have it made) out of metal.

Comment: the 3D printing option is an option - but as I'd need the model created as well, it could be expensive - but thanks.   As for "Shopping"   I was kinda hoping a knowledgeable plumber or other person already had this problem and had a source - since I've spend much time searching myself.    Sorry.